# Data truncation for date field

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm stuck on one error in my struts2 + hibernate application. I'm trying to save a entity on the DB and I get this exception message:

```
Incorrect date value: '' for column 'data_creazione' at row 1
```

This is my code :

```
...
    DocumentoCondivisoDAO cdao = new  DocumentoCondivisoDAO();
    DocumentoCondiviso doc = new DocumentoCondiviso("test_document", "mime/tipe", new Date(), 100000, utente, null);        
    cdao.save(doc);
```

This is the debugging information :

```
Hibernate: insert into ts_documenti_condivisi (data_creazione, id_destinatario, dimensione_documento, nome_documento, id_proprietario, tipo_documento) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

---

```
16:05:08,798 TRACE TimestampType:133 - binding '2014-02-11 16:05:03' to parameter: 1
16:05:08,798 TRACE TimestampType:133 - binding '2014-02-11 16:05:03' to parameter: 1
16:05:08,798 TRACE TimestampType:133 - binding '2014-02-11 16:05:03' to parameter: 1
16:05:08,808 TRACE IntegerType:126 - binding null to parameter: 2
16:05:08,808 TRACE IntegerType:126 - binding null to parameter: 2
16:05:08,808 TRACE IntegerType:126 - binding null to parameter: 2
16:05:08,819 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '111111' to parameter: 3
16:05:08,819 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '111111' to parameter: 3
16:05:08,819 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '111111' to parameter: 3
16:05:08,827 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'documento' to parameter: 4
16:05:08,827 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'documento' to parameter: 4
16:05:08,827 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'documento' to parameter: 4
16:05:08,834 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '27' to parameter: 5
16:05:08,834 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '27' to parameter: 5
16:05:08,834 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '27' to parameter: 5
16:05:08,842 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'aas' to parameter: 6
16:05:08,842 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'aas' to parameter: 6
16:05:08,842 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'aas' to parameter: 6
16:05:08,966 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'data_creazione' at row 1
16:05:08,966 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'data_creazione' at row 1
```

I want to clarify that the same code in another class works like a charm... what am I doing wrong?

EDIT1: constructor

```
public DocumentoCondiviso(String nomeDocumento, String tipoDocumento, Date dataCreazione,
                            int dimensioneDocumento, Utenti proprietario, Utenti destinatario){

    this.nomeDocumento = nomeDocumento;
    this.tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento;
    this.dataCreazione = dataCreazione;
    this.dimensioneDocumento = dimensioneDocumento;
    this.proprietario = proprietario;
    this.destinatario = destinatario;

}
```

The field type on MySQL database is "DATE"....i have a lot of entity similar to this that are working perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the DocumentoCondiviso() constructor? Are you assigning the value please check. Also, check the column data type.